# Не работает поиск элемента

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь найти в массиве слово mp3, перебирая каждое значение массива, но выводит программа только значек ошибки "0".

```
g='0'
s=['mp3']
for i in range (0):
    if 'mp3' in s[i]:
        print()
        g=s[i]
        break
print(g)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что вы проходите циклом по `range(0)`, то есть цикла не будет и данный блок кода просто пропустится.

Вот более красивый вариант прохода по списку:

```
g='0'
s=['mp3']
for word in s:
    if 'mp3' in word:
        print()
        g=word
        break
print(g)
```

так же хочу добавить, что конструкция `if 'mp3' in word` будет давать истину, когда mp3 является частью слова, если вы хотите полное совпадение, то используйте `if word == 'mp3'`

Comment: Большое спасибо, но я не совсем понимаю как работает for word in s, это бесконечный цикл?

Comment: Нет, это не бесконечный цикл. Суть конструкции `for <item> in <some_list>` заключается в том, что вы перебираете каждый элемент списка, который помешается в переменную `<item>` 

Если бы у вас был список `s=['mp3', 'mp4']`, то в первой итерации `word` был бы mp3, а во-второй уже 'mp4', после чего бы цикл остановился

Comment: Если вы уберёте `break`, то цикл будет проходить по оставшимся элементам списка даже после нахождения совпадения, но закончится после того, как проверит последний элемент. `break` в данном случае останавливает цикл после первого найденного совпадения

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Без циклов.

Находится ли элемент в списке:

```
s=['mp32']
word = 'mp3'

if word in s:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('совсем не ok')
```

Количество элементов в списке:

```
print (s.count(word))
```

Или с условием:

```
if s.count(word) > 0: ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Исправленный код ниже.

`range` в исходном коде ни разу не сработает из-за 0, предлагаемого, как количество "прогонов". В таких случаях лучше привязываться к длине списка, по которому проходим.

```
g='0'
s=['mp3']
for i in range (len(s)):
    if 'mp3' in s[i]:
        print()
        g=s[i]
        break
print(g)
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)